# Running python program from php

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I have python file in /usr/local/bin
I can run it anywhere in server using `addid.py --id [id]`

And now I need to run it from php file: `add.php?id=[id]`

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$command = "addid.py --id $id";
$job = shell_exec($command);
echo $job;
print '<hr/>';
print $command;
?>
```

Page loads faster, but python program actually works longer (~30 seconds). Also cannot see python program in `htop` (task manager). It prints < hr > line and result of $command (string).

Also added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

What is wrong?

Comment: You should really, really be doing `$id = escapeshellarg($_GET["id"])`  if you don't want your system to be taken over.

Comment: @dave ,Thanks for useful information, but its not for public usage, thats why we don't think about possible hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command needs to invoke the python interpreter, right now it is just a file name.

```
$id = escapeshellarg($_GET["id"]); 
$command = "python addid.py --id $id";
$job = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: its in /usr/local/bin/ and it have `#!/usr/bin/python` in header. So in shell I can just type addid.py and it works. Same in shell script and cron job. No need for writing python before program name.